# Python read file into memory for repeated FTP copy

Tags: python, windows, ftp

I need to read a local file and copy to remote location with FTP, I copy same file file.txt to remote location repeatedly hundreds of times with different names like f1.txt, f2.txt... f1000.txt etc. Now, is it necessary to always open, read, close my local file.txt for every single FTP copy or is there a way to store into a variable and use that all time and avoid file open, close functions. file.txt is small file of 6KB. Below is the code I am using

```
for i in range(1,101):
    fname = 'file'+ str(i) +'.txt'
    fp = open('file.txt', 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + fname, fp)
    fp.close()
```

I tried reading into a string variable and replace fp but ftp.storbinary requires second argument to have method read(), please suggest if there is better way to avoid file open close or let me know if it has no performance improvement at all. I am using python 2.7.10 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply open it before the loop, and close it after:

```
fp = open('file.txt', 'rb')

for i in range(1,101):
    fname = 'file'+ str(i) +'.txt'
    fp.seek(0)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + fname, fp)

fp.close()
```

**Update** Make sure you add `fp.seek(0)` before the call to `ftp.storbinary`, otherwise the `read` call will exhaust the file in the first iteration as noted by @eryksun.

**Update 2** depending on the size of the file it will probably be faster to use `BytesIO`. This way the file content is saved in memory but will still be a file-like object (ie it will have a `read` method).

```
from io import BytesIO

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    output = BytesIO()
    output.write(f.read())

for i in range(1, 101):
    fname = 'file' + str(i) + '.txt'
    output.seek(0)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + fname, fp)
```

Comment: That wont work, it copies only once and second copy never works

Comment: You're missing `fp.seek(0)` to reset the file pointer to the beginning.

Comment: @eryksun Indeed, forgot that, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Would it not be better to just keep the content of file in memory and close the file? What is the purpose of reading it repeatedly?

Comment: @Divisadero The problem is that `ftp.storbinary` expects the second argument it receives to have a `read()` method, so simply storing the file content as string won't work. Using `StringIO` MIGHT work, but I didn't try it.

Comment: BytesIO, StringIO - try to use that, it will be at faster and cleaner

Comment: @eryksun and DeepSpace fp.seek(0) and BytesIO() seem to be the answers I was looking for. Since we are still keeping file open for long, I hope it is still better than opening and closing so many times

Comment: @RAFIQ In the code under Update 2 in my answer, the file is opened and closed immediately, and only once. And yes, performance wise this method saves you a lot of i/o actions thus reducing the time the script takes.

Comment: @DeepSpace True, we are doing same thing indirectly leaving file.txt closed, BytesIO holding file.

Comment: Using `BytesIO` avoids having to repeatedly copy from the system cache to a temporary buffer. This may improve performance, depending on the relative cost of surrounding operations. Another option, especially for a large file in a 64-bit process, is to use a memory-mapped filelike object, e.g. `mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)`.